# Jsons doesn't load after upgrading the phonegap version to cli-5.4

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an application using phonegap and builds using phonegap build. 
Previously I used phonegap version 3.7. With that version I was able to load data to my app and make them display. 
But I had to update the version to cli-5.4 to initiate push notifications. After that it does not load json. But all others working fine. 
Somebody please explain what should I have to do. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It could be a whitelist problem. Whitelist in Android was moved to a [dedicated plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) due to security problems in Cordova 4 I think. Also have a look at the [whitelist guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/appdev/whitelist/)